# Output value from div

Tags: javascript, html

I have code:

```
<div class="price-txt">145 GAR</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Results that I want is put the value from div between`<p>` like:

*145 GAR*

*145*

I've made JS

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

But the results is only

145 GAR

undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the javascript code to the below code.You can also check the fiddler.

https://jsfiddle.net/7byw93f4/

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt")[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `innerHTML`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt").value;
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = x;
```

```html
<div class="price-txt">145 GAR</div> <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt")[0];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.innerText; // You can use innerHTML
```

```html
<div class="price-txt">145 GAR</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

1. `value` is not a prop of `div` element.
   You should use `input` instead of `div` or you can get the node text instead of `value`.
2. this codes `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt")`,  the `x` is a array, so you can put `[0]` to get the element that you need. Check my snipet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `split` splits the string on the basis of paramenter inside bracket, here `split(" ")` split string d on the whitespace.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price-txt")[0].textContent;
var res = x.split(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0];
```

```html
<div class="price-txt">145 GAR</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```